# How can I rollback to earlier versions of a Visual Studio project while developing locally?

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, backup, versioning

In the process of building an ASP.NET Core MVC rc1 application with SQL databases, c#, bootstrap, angular, css, javascript, javascript dependencies, package managers like bower, or any visual studio project for that matter, I sometimes break the application and would like to roll it back to a previous state when the application was working.

What are some techniques/the best way to create incremental versions, save and flag working versions, and rollback to earlier versions especially when a project has so many moving parts, technologies, and dependencies?

I would prefer a technique that exists inside Visual Studio, or the most standard/popular Microsoft or open source technique or tool that may be free.

I also would like the option to do the backups on my local machine rather than on an external server.

Comment: Please use the proper tags in future! When your quesiton is related to ASP.NET Core use "asp.net-core" tag ! NOT "asp.net" and "core", both are completely unrelated to your question. Please read the tag descriptions before adding them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone else has this question: I found Git to be a great way to achieve this purpose. Unlike many version control systems, it keeps the change repository on the local machine and only places it on a server when the project is merged. As of 2015, it integrates well with Visual Studio and TFS. Here is a video from the Build conference explaining its integration with VS2015:

Channel 9 - using git in visual studio
https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2015/3-746